# MySQL - Update join natural order

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to update a table (t2) from values in another one (t1). t1 has multiple values for the same key, and I would like t2 to get the **last** value of each key. The problem is I get the **first** value for each key.

Here is a simplified schema:

`Table t1
+--------+-----------+
| key    | value     | 
|    A   |   1       |
|    B   |   5       |
|    B   |   6       |
|    C   |   2       |
+--------+-----------+
Table t2
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| key    | value     | col       | 
|    A   |   null    |   xxx     |
|    B   |   null    |   yyy     |
|    C   |   null    |   zzz     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+`

My update query:

```
`UPDATE t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t2.key = t1.key SET t2.value = t1.value`
```

And the result I get:

`Table t2
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| key    | value     | col       | 
|    A   |   1       |   xxx     |
|    B   |   5       |   yyy     |
|    C   |   2       |   zzz     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+`

And the result I would like:

`Table t2
+--------+-----------+-----------+
| key    | value     | col       | 
|    A   |   1       |   xxx     |
|    B   |   6       |   yyy     |
|    C   |   2       |   zzz     |
+--------+-----------+-----------+`

The only difference is I want to have the last value for key B, so **6** instead of **5**.

I know it is not possible to put an ORDER BY in an UPDATE with JOINS, moreover I don't have any column to order the t1 table (I could create one auto-increment column in t1 and ORDER BY this column DESC).

How can I achieve my goal?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the last value per key in t1 is (always) the highest value for that key, you could use `MAX`:

```
UPDATE t2 INNER JOIN t1 on t2.key = t1.key SET t2.value = (SELECT MAX(t1.value) FROM t1 WHERE t2.key = t1.key)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply; actually my table t1 has random values, so I cannot use your solution.